# Live football stats API

Tags: rss, statistics

I'm looking for a service that will provide live football/soccer statistics (match and player stats, preferably) over API or RSS (or whatever), or perhaps just provide easily parsable stats.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Press Association](http://www.pressassociation.com/sport/sports/football.html) has what you need, although also not free.

Comment: wow,that's what i call quick answer! great links, this is exactly what i need.

thanks again for all answers!

Comment: its a good one.. not free though

Answer (score 1):

After a little big of googling I found this article which might be helpful to you:

http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10358477

Someone else asked the very same question in this forum and they linked to the following [site](http://www.pressassociation.com/sport.html) which provides RSS feeds of results for several sports.

Comment: At least summarise the page instead of a link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xmlTeam.com provides stats for NFL, NBA, MLB, NHL and NCAA.
Their feeds are not free, but they do have multiple price-points.